# How to determine apk package name from search results

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

On Alpine Linux, given the results of an `apk search`, how do I determine the package name to give to `apk add`?

For example, suppose I forgot the how to spell "lighttpd", or I forgot exactly what the package name was.  I might do an `apk search "lightt*"` which yields the following on my machine (a Docker image):

```
lighttpd-mod_auth-1.4.45-r1
acf-lighttpd-0.6.0-r2
lighttpd-mod_webdav-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-doc-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-dbg-1.4.45-r1
```

Given the above, how do I figure out that I need to type `apk add lighttpd`?  I naively typed in `apk add lighttpd-1.4.45-r1` and it gave an error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  lighttpd-1.4.45-r1 (missing):
    required by: world[lighttpd-1.4.45-r1]
```

I'm used to things like `apt-cache search` on Debian, where each line of the search results includes *exactly* the package name to type into `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `apk search` to not include version numbers by passing it `-q/--quiet`:

```
$ apk -q search "lightt*"
lighttpd-mod_auth
acf-lighttpd
lighttpd-mod_webdav
lighttpd
lighttpd-doc
lighttpd-dbg
```

If you want to find out what version a package provides, it gets a bit more awkward:

```
apk info lighttpd | head -n1 | sed 's/^lighttpd-\(.*\) description:/\1/g'
```

Here's a simple function to get the version for a package:

```
apkver() {
    apk info "$1" | head -n1 | sed "s/^$1-\(.*\) description:/\1/g"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue is most likely because `apk` repos aren't updated.

It works fine for me.

```
monitor:~# apk search lighttpd
lighttpd-mod_auth-1.4.45-r1
acf-lighttpd-0.6.0-r2
lighttpd-mod_webdav-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-doc-1.4.45-r1
lighttpd-dbg-1.4.45-r1
monitor:~# apk add lighttpd
(1/10) Installing libev (4.24-r0)
(2/10) Installing libintl (0.19.8.1-r1)
(3/10) Installing libmount (2.28.2-r2)
(4/10) Installing glib (2.52.1-r0)
(5/10) Installing gamin (0.1.10-r10)
(6/10) Installing db (5.3.28-r0)
(7/10) Installing libsasl (2.1.26-r10)
....
```

So try first with `apk update`.

Comment: What I meant was, from the string "lighttpd-1.4.45-r1", how do I know that I need to type in "lighttpd" as the package name?  How do I know which trailing numbers and dashes are required and which are not?

Comment: You don't need version number, unless you install specific version. Just tested.